# websocket connection closed immediately on nginx tornado

Tags: javascript, nginx, websocket, tornado

I am really very tried to configure tornado websocket connection configuration with nginx finally I got one issue but i cannot fix it. Is I made any mistake in my configuration?
This is my websocket.py:

```
class Application(tornado.web.Application):


   def __init__(self):

       handlers = [
            (r"/", ChatSocketHandler)
       ]
       settings = dict(

        cookie_secret="__TODO:_GENERATE_YOUR_OWN_RANDOM_VALUE_HERE__",
        template_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 
          "templates"),
        static_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static"),
        xsrf_cookies=False,
        debug = True
    )
    super(Application, self).__init__(handlers, **settings)

class ChatSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):

    def check_origin(self, origin):
       return True
    def open(self, *args, **kwargs):
       print('connection opened')

    def on_close(self):
         print('connection closed')
    def on_message(self, message):
         print(message)
         self.write_message(message)
```

This is my client script:

```
<script>

  let url = "ws://104.131.115.151:8888/";
  let socket = new WebSocket(url);
  socket.onmessage = function(event) {
      console.log(event);
  };
  socket.onopen = function () {
     console.log('opend');
     socket.send('Hello World')
  };
  socket.onclose = function () {
      console.log('closed');
  };

</script>
```

In my web browser console:

```
opened
closed
```

When run on local without nginx configuration:

```
opened
MessageEvent{...}
```

---

This is my nginx configuration:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        ''      close;
 }
upstream pythonserver {

    server 127.0.0.1:8888;

}
server{
         listen 80;
         server_name 209.97.139.107;

         location /chatsocket {

              proxy_pass http://pythonserver;
              proxy_redirect off;
              proxy_set_header Host $host;
              proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
              proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
              proxy_buffers 8 32k;
              proxy_buffer_size 64k;
              proxy_read_timeout 86400s;
              proxy_send_timeout 86400s;
              keepalive_timeout 90;
              proxy_cache off;
              proxy_buffering off;
              proxy_http_version 1.1;
              proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
              proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
              include         uwsgi_params;
              uwsgi_pass unix:/home/apideveloper/api/app.sock;

        }
        location / {
              include         uwsgi_params;
              uwsgi_pass unix:/home/apideveloper/api/app.sock;

        }
}
```

Also I am using https://digitalocean.com cloud and my server url http://209.97.139.107/

Answer (score 1):

It is quite likely that your nginx config is incomplete.

When a browser tries to connect to a websocket, it sends `Upgrade` and `Connection` http headers. This tells the server to upgrade the connection to websocket.

The problem (and it is a common problem) seems to be that the browser is sending the upgrade headers to nginx, but nginx is not sending those headers back to Tornado. For a successful websocket connection, the upgrade headers must reach your Tornado backend.

**Solution:**

The solution is to tell Nginx to send the upgrade headers back to Tornado so that the websocket connection can complete.

Your configuration should look like this:

```
location / {
    # ... other variables ...

    # variables for websocket
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
}
```

Reload your Nginx server and it should work.

Comment: I tried this also but won't work see my nginx configuration below.